# Correct use of JSON for a simple restaurant menu description

Tags: javascript, json, validation, encoding

I would like to know whether this JSON script example I made is well formatted and whether it does make sense to put the information like this.

```
{"menu": {
  "drinks": [
    {"coke": "20"},
    {"pepsi": "20"},
    {"water": "20"}
  ],
  "junk-food": [
    {"hamburger": "40"},
    {"fries": "20"},
    {"pizza": "20"}
  ]
}}
```

I already validated the script with http://jsonlint.com/ but still I would like to a little more since I'm very new.

For some context on the use of the script, I'm going to parse the script with Python.

It is meant to organize elements of a GUI that will look more or less like this:

[image]

On the second window, a listbox similar to the first one will appear with the corresponding item and respective price.

- Is it correct JSON?
- Does this structure make sense?

Comment: I would put all of the items in the same array, with a "category" property- or better yet, an array of category properties. That way `fries` can be `junk-food` and also a `side-dish` and `appetizer`.

Comment: How would you model the objects?  Do that first.

Comment: @DerekBeattie I'm not sure how to do that really, it is almost my first go with JSON. I will try though. Thanks!

Comment: @evan I don't understand exactly what you are suggesting. If I put every item in an array, how would I identify which category that item is?

Comment: I would give each item an ID as well, and make it clearer what the price is. Like `"coke": {id: 1, price: 20}`. Also note I removed the `""` because it's a number, and would semantically be used better without `""`.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks! I will definitely remove the `""`, this makes a lot of sense. On the other hand I don't understand how would the id help to figure out what the price is.

Comment: coke should not be the key. coke should be the value of the name property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON is correct. The structure doesn't have much semantic meaning though. I changed the structure so that it has more meaning and will be more manageable when attributes are added.

```
{"menu": {
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"coke",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":"drinks",
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"pepsi",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":"drinks",
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"water",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":"drinks",
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"hamburger",
            "qty": 40,
            "category":"junk food",
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"fries",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":"junk food",
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"pizza",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":"junk food",
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        }
    ]
}}
```

to save space you could do something like this too,

```
{"menu": {
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"coke",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":0,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"pepsi",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":0,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"water",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":0,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"hamburger",
            "qty": 40,
            "category":1,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"fries",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":1,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        },
        {
            "name":"pizza",
            "qty": 20,
            "category":1,
            "sizes":["small","large"]
        }
    ],
    "categories":[
        "drinks",
        "junk food"
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, it definitely looks better! BTW, the number was prize not quantity, not that it makes much of a difference. +1!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I don't really need to save much space since this information won't be transmitted, it will just be read by python once at the application startup, so there isn't much need for optimization there.

Comment: Well , it depends on what sort of information is more important. If priority is finding all the items in a category , then this structure would be somewhat bad for that task.

Comment: One more question. I see a possible problem with this, let's say I have two pepsis, one small an one big, how would you recommend me to point out that they should be presented together? One after the other?

Comment: @tereško I agree. You'll need to do a pass over the data to get all items in the same category. The reason I did this is because I  try to avoid is using data as the key. That way you're less likely to iterate over a json response and try to access a property that was not returned by the server. Also a key can't have a space. That is why junk food was junk-food.

Comment: @sissonb I had forgot to accept your answer, I'm sorry. Here it is and again thanks for you very helpful answer!